# Why I am not getting space in between words of my final String after I reverse the sentence in Python?

Tags: python, string

So, I am solving a Leetcode question where I am given a string and I have to reverse all the words from it and return the reversed phrase. Below is the problem statement

> Given an input string s, reverse the order of the words.
>
> A word is defined as a sequence of non-space characters. The words in s will be separated by at least one space.
>
> Return a string of the words in reverse order concatenated by a single space.
>
> Note that s may contain leading or trailing spaces or multiple spaces between two words. The returned string should only have a single space separating the words. Do not include any extra spaces.**
>
> Example :
>
> Input: s = "the sky is blue"
>
> Output: "blue is sky the"

But the output I am getting is as follows **blueisskythe**. I did try to add space ahead of .join() but I am not getting output that I want . Below is my code

This is the code I wrote:

```py
class Solution(object):
    def reverseWords(self,str1):
        ss = str1.split(' ')
        final_str = ""
        for i in range(len(ss)-1,-1,-1):
            final_str += "".join(ss[i])
        return final_str
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    str = "the sky is blue"
    print(Solution().reverseWords(str))
```

Comment: Because you've split on spaces, so you removed them, and then you don't put them back in? Reverse the list, then glue it back up with spaces.

Comment: What would be the correct approach here ?

Comment: `"".join(ss[i])` is the same as `ss[i]`. Why do you think you need to join a string to make a string?

Comment: Sorry, I thought since join has "" ahead of it , it will automatically put a space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Approach what you might like:*

```py
class Solution(object):
    @staticmethod
    def reverse_word(input_str: str) -> str:
        # Split the string into words
        words = input_str.split()

        # Reverse the order of the words
        reversed_words = words[::-1]

        # Join them
        reversed_string = " ".join(reversed_words)

        return reversed_string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_str = "the sky is blue"
    print(Solution.reverse_word(input_str))
```

*My suggestion to your code:*

- Consider avoiding names that shadow built-in types, like `str`, as it can lead to confusion and unexpected behavior.
- String concatenation in a loop (`final_str += "".join(ss[i]`)
  Consider using a list to store the reversed words and then joining them.
- Unconventional naming style (`str1`) and method signature
  And it's more common to use `snake_case` for variable and function names in Python.
  Instead of `reverseWords`, you can consider the replacement with `reverse_words`
- Utility of `@staticmethod`
  For the current context, using `@staticmethod` is appropriate because the 'reverseWords' method doesn't rely on any instance-specific `attributes` or `methods` of the class.
  Alternatively, you could make `reverse_words` a class method (`@classmethod`) if there's a potential future need.

*Conclusion:*
My suggestion is `not` absolutely true but it's advisable to follow best `practices` to write clean, robust, reusable `pythonic` codebase.

Have a great day!